# How do we load a html file from a folder on a sdcard into a webview panel?

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Every time a character is made in my app it is saved to an html file named after it in a folder called RpgApp on the sdcard

so if the characters name is john smith then there will be a john-smith.htm located in RpgApp folder on the sdcard
now that bit works great

the app also makes a list of buttons each one named after a file inside the RpgApp folder (so in this case there would be a button named john-smith.html ) and the content is the same as the name so it displays as john-smith.html
each button has the following method on click

```
private void htmlButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        string curDir = externalDevices.ToString();
        Button button = sender as Button;
        Uri result = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/RpgApp/"+button.Name,curDir));
        web.Navigate(result);

    }
```

now the idea is that when you click the button the webview control (aptly named "web") loads up the content of the file (you notice button.name as part of the url? well thats because the buttons name is the file name :)

but instead the browser remains unmoved, just sits thier blank

to test i changed web.Navigate(result); to web.NavigateToString(button.Name);
and sure enough when ever i clicked a button the webview displayed the name of the button i clicked

any ideas?

NOTE:
This is webview for windows phone 8.1, it replaces phone:WebBrowser that was in windows phone 8.
One of the reasons im having such difficulty (been trying to get this work since 9am) is webview is also the name of the android web control, thats making it hard to find info thats relevent to windows 8.1

the app hass access to the sdcard, and it is the app that makes the folder and files we are reading or trying to read, seems when it comes to files what SHOULD work doesnt, its very frustrating.

The solution after some help from WPMed

```
private async void htmlButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        string fileContent;
        StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        StorageFolder sdcard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault(); 
        var dataFolder = await sdcard.GetFolderAsync("RpgApp");
        var file = await dataFolder.GetFileAsync(button.Content.ToString());
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
        {
           fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); 
        }
        web.NavigateToString(fileContent);
    }

}
```

seems microsoft for whatever reason, dont want you loading html files locally (unless in isolated folders locked away from user access, some security concern?)
So as WPMed pointed out you have to load the file into a string and then load the string into the webview panel, needlessly complicated seems to be the microsoft way, but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN writes this:

> To load uncompressed and unencrypted content from your app’s LocalFolder or TemporaryFolder data stores, use the Navigate method with a Uri that uses the ms-appdata scheme. The WebView support for this scheme requires you to place your content in a subfolder under the local or temporary folder.

So it seems like if you want to load an html stored in a different folder, it is not supported. However, you can read the content of the file to a string, and than you can use `web.NavigateToString(yourHtmlInString)`. (NavigateToString is used to load an html in a string format to a WebView, that's why the name of the button you clicked was displayed)

Comment: I used .navigateToString to test the webview was working and that the buttons were getting the correct name. The character files will be quite detailed with anchors linking to various sections of the file. html is the perfect form for this.

If your right (and no reason your not) that means i have two choices
1)use local storage so i can display the data inside the app BUT the user will have no way to access the file or delete the file
2)use the sdcard, user has full control of the files, as intended but i cant display it in the app

microsoft make some wierd challenges for programmers :(

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. In case 2), you CAN display the data you need. As I wrote, read the content of your whatever.html into a string, and call NavigateToString. That will display the html properly, trust me I use it.

Comment: ah i see, though no idea how to convert a file to a string, i foresee much googling in my future lol (tips great-fully appreciated) 
i did do a test with a static string and yeah it even used the html tags correctly
thank you

Comment: ;) Here's a quickstart for reading files, really useful, and quite easy to do: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx than you're ready to go :)

Comment: well so far i have http://pastebin.com/YtZReQj0
no errors but it just results in a blank webviewer (it turns white so its loading quite possibly a blank string)

Comment: indeed, i edited the main post to show the solution i went with (refined it a bit more since then, ofcourse but should help the next person that has the issue :) )
thanks again, if it wasnt for your help i would still be trying to load up the html file into the web browser lol (silly me thinking that html files go into a browser :) wonder why microsoft took this route, got to be a reason somewhere)

Comment: cool, than I'm glad I could help :) Maybe someone with more experience will point out a better approach... Until then It'll do the job :)